# Processing Json data into pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a requirement where i need to load Json data into pig but it seems there is some problem that i can't load the data. Below is sample data structure -

```
[{

  "id": 1,

  "first_name": "Lakshmi",

  "last_name": "P",

  "email": "xxx@yyy.com",

  "gender": "Female",

  "ip_address": "26.58.193.2"

}, {

  "id": 2,

  "first_name": "Syam",

  "last_name": "Prasad",

  "email": "sp@yyy.com",

  "gender": "Male",

  "ip_address": "229.179.4.212"

}, {

  "id": 3,

  "first_name": "ABC",

  "last_name": "CDE",

  "email": "abc@cde.com",

  "gender": "Female",

  "ip_address": "180.66.162.255"

}, {

  "id": 4,

  "first_name": "FGS",

  "last_name": "IJK",

  "email": "lmn@opq.com",

  "gender": "Male",

  "ip_address": "67.76.188.26"

}]
```

I tried to load the data using JsonLoader as in the below code -

```
--inidata1 = load 'inputData1.json' using JsonStorage('\n');
--REGISTER 'piggybank-0.15.0.jar';
inidata = load 'inputData1.json' using JsonLoader('id:int,first_name:chararray,last_name:chararray,email:chararray,gender:chararray,ip_address:$

madata = foreach inidata generate group, FLATTEN(inidata);

dump madata;

--filterdata = foreach inidata generate id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address;

--dump filterdata;
--filterdata = foreach inidata generate id,gender,first_name,last_name;

--selecteddata = filter inidata by (gender=='Male') OR (last_name=='Prasad');

--dump selecteddata;
--store selecteddata into 'JSON-DATA_input';
```

Could anyone please share if there is any fix?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't load" - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

JsonLoader expects each row of data to be a json object separated by newlines, so your data would look something like:

```
{  "id": 1,  "first_name": "Lakshmi",  "last_name": "P",  "email": "xxx@yyy.com",  "gender": "Female",  "ip_address": "26.58.193.2"}
{  "id": 2,  "first_name": "Syam",  "last_name": "Prasad",  "email": "sp@yyy.com",  "gender": "Male",  "ip_address": "229.179.4.212"}
```

Instead you have it wrapped in an array--I don't think pig's JsonLoader can even load that without giving it a key and wrapping it in a json object, based on my tests.

This example was helpful for me: http://joshualande.com/read-write-json-apache-pig

Also, if the code you posted was copied correctly, it's malformed:

```
inidata = load 'inputData1.json' using JsonLoader('id:int,first_name:chararray,last_name:chararray,email:chararray,gender:chararray,ip_address:$
```

isn't ended correctly, it should be more like:

```
inidata = load 'inputData1.json' using JsonLoader('id:int,first_name:chararray,last_name:chararray,email:chararray,gender:chararray,ip_address:chararray');
```